# The general linear group over the complex numbers conjugate some proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Let $G = Gl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ and let $H = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} \ |\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}, ac \neq 0 \right\}$. Prove that every element of G is conjugate to some element of the subgroup H.

That is we need to prove that following $G = gHg^{-1}$, so we need to show that for every matrix in G it is similar to matrices of H or that is at least what I think we should do ? However I am not sure if my reasoning is correct as its leading me to big calculations and I got lost while calculating general eigenvector of element $A \in Gl_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Did you learn about canonical forms?

Comment: no I didn't learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results, say, from *Jordan normal form* over $\mathbf C$. Or from the theorem that a matrix can be put in triangular form by a change of basis if and only if its characteristic/minimal polynomials split over the base field into linear factors, which is the case when the base field is the algebraically closed field $\mathbf C$.

Comment: I don't know about such results.

Comment: But you know the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Yes I do know about it.

Comment: So you know the matrix can be diagonalised if the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is equal to its algebraic multiplicity? And you know what happens if it is less?

Comment: Yes, then it is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Do I have get an arbitrarily element $A \in GLn(R)$ and show that A is diagonalizable, then show the diagonal matrix generated by that is an element of H ?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalisable, the diagonal consists of the eigen value, which cannot be $0$ if the matrix is invertible. So this case is settled. When $A$ is not diagonalisable, it can put in triangular form; one of these forms is Jordan's canonical form, which consists in the eigenvalues on the diagonal, and $0$ or $1$ onthe overdiagonal. If you don't this, you have to take an arbitrary $2\times2$ invertible matrix $P$, and show you can choose coefficients of this matrix in such a way that $P^{-1}AP$  has a $0$ in the lower left corner.

Comment: How can I choose those coefficients ? if their a systematic way to do this I guess I need to solve the algebraic way to get P ?

Comment: You write unknown coefficients , say $u,v,h,k$, and other coefficients $a, b,c, d$ for the matrix $A$, and compute the coefficient of the  lower left corner. This will result in an equation with $4$ unknowns and $4$ parameters. This equation is linear in one of the unknowns. There is a constraint: the determinant must be non-zero.

Comment: okay yeah I see alright thank you.